# How to Change an Attribute of a Class with another Plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Plugin Which have a Class and an Attribute of that Class defined as :

```
    class WC_Customer_Order_XML_Export_Suite_Generator {

    public function __construct( $export_type ) {

    $this->root_element = apply_filters( 'wc_customer_order_xml_export_suite_xml_root_element', ucfirst( $export_type ) );

    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the Value of `root_element` Using another plugin, without changing this Plugins code? **If Yes Then Please Let me know How can I do this...**

Comment: Filter the value using the `wc_customer_order_xml_export_suite_xml_root_element` hook.

Comment: Thank you so much Sally... It was really Helpful... thanks again!

Comment: No problem, and I've provided some example `function`s.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to my comment, here are some example `function`s:

Example #1:

```
add_filter( 'wc_customer_order_xml_export_suite_xml_root_element', function ( $elem ) {
    return 'something';
} );
```

Example #2:

```
add_filter( 'wc_customer_order_xml_export_suite_xml_root_element', function ( $elem ) {
    if ( 'a' === $elem ) {
        return 'b';
    }

    // $elem is b, c, d, etc.
    return $elem;
} );
```